# Не срабатывает событие keyup у компонента searchControl

Tags: yandex-maps-api

При заполнении поискового поля в Яндекс-карте должно заполняться внешнее текстовое поле.

Пытаюсь реализовать следующим образом:

```js
const searchControl = ref.controls.get('searchControl');

console.log('events', searchControl.events);
    
// в свойстве types вижу submit, keyup и другие

searchControl.events.add('keyup', function () {
    
  // но сюда во время поиска почему-то не доходит
      
  console.log('keyup', searchControl.getRequestString());

}, this);
```

Событие keyup почему-то не отрабатывает.

При этом событие submit работает отлично. Но оно не подходит по задаче.

Как быть?

P.S. Использую Яндекс API 2.1

Answer (score 1):

Событие submit описано в документации и поэтому срабатывает https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/#event-submit 
 События keyup в документации нет https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/#event-clear

Answer (score 0):

Метод `getRequestString()` возвращает текст поискового запроса, который формируется только в момент поиска. В процессе ввода и заполнения поля запрос ещё не совершен и поэтому методу нечего вернуть.

Доступные события для контрола поиска описаны [в документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/?from=SO#events-summary). API Поддерживает только событие `submit` - оно срабатывает, когда запрос в поиск сделан и его текст доступен через `getRequestString()`.

События `keyup` у поисковой строки нет.